# Limit the number of rows with same record in one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a long list of people's names. There are hundreds of people with the last name Smith, hundreds of people with the last name Kim, etc.

How can I select all the people in the table, but only allow a maximum of 6 people with the same last name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is probably to use variables:

```
select ll.*
from (select ll.*,
             (@rn := if(@ln = lastname, @rn + 1,
                        if(@ln := lastname, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from longlist ll cross join
           (select @ln := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by lastname
     ) ll
where rn <= 6;
```

Comment: Where 'lastname' is the column name?

Comment: @jairbow . . . Yes.

Comment: I really wish there was a built in way to do this, but this method does exactly what I asked for.

Comment: @jairbow . . . The `row_number()` function is built into most databases.

Comment: I didn't know about that function, so, thank you. I'm using MariaDB, which has it in version 10.2. At this moment 10.2 is in Alpha.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do what you want, some of them very complicated.   Any deterministic method will [rank the rows](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#rank.rows).  Your task is to join the table to itself, and decide what makes one "Smith" less than another.

Once you have ranked names, you can join them to the table again (or use `where exists`) and `where rank < 7` or whatever.